# Call to protected method App\Http\Middleware\Admin::handle() from context 'Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline'

Tags: php, laravel

i am really new to Laravel. I try to create page by follow  some youtube tutorial. It goes fine suddenly there got error in call to protect method from context pipeline. I try to search in Stackoverflow regard that error but could'nt. I hope anyone can help to tell me what the exact problem are here. below i attach my code;

Route:

```
Route::get('/','Adminauth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('login','Adminauth\AuthController@login');
Route::group(array('middleware'=>'Admin'),function(){
Route::get('/dashboard','Admin\AdminControll@dashboard');
Route::get('/logout','Adminauth\AuthController@logout');
});
Route::get('/create',function(){
    App\User::create([
         'name' => 'sara',
         'username'=>'sara',
         'email' => 'sara@yahoo.com.my',
         'password' => bcrypt('******'),
            ]);
});
```

There got two controller inside folder
Admin and adminauth
Admin Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AdminControll extends Controller
{
   public function __construct ()
   {
    $this->middleware('Admin');
   }
   public function dashboard()
   {
    return view('Admin.layout');
   }
}
```

AuthController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Adminauth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Auth;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;
    protected $redirecTo = '/dashboard';
    protected $guard = 'Admin';
    public Function showLoginForm()
    {
        if(Auth::guard('Admin')->check())
        {
            return redirect('/dashboard');
        }
        return view ('login');

    }
    public function logout(){
        Auth::guard('Admin')->logout();
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Middleware(Admin.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Admin
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     * @param  mixed
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string|null $guard
     */
    protected function handle($request,Closure $next,$guard = 'Admin')
    {
        if(!Auth::guard($guard)->check()){
return redirect('/');
        }
 return $next($request);
}
    }
```

kernel.php

```
   */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'Admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Middleware(Admin.php)` make the `handle` method's visibility to `public`.

Laravel is not able to access the `handle` method outside of the Admin class because it is set to `protected`.

Answer (score 0):

The `handle()` method should be public, like this:

```
public function handle($request,Closure $next,$guard = 'Admin')
```